# Ignoring loopback messages in Qpid/AMQP?

Tags: amqp, qpid

Is there a way to ignore messages that come from yourself in Qpid/AMQP?  I've dug around both the documentation and the source for qpid, and can't find a flag that lets me ignore them.  It seems like something that would be passed to exchangeBind().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [no-local flag on the basic.consume method](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.no-local)?

Comment: It appears qpid has a similar flag, but only on a per-session basis.  I was hoping for something that I could set on each binding to flag whether that specific message binding allowed loopback messages.

Comment: The above flag is mandated by the Amqp spec, it depends which version you're using.  The link I posted if for Amqp 0.9.1 - you may be using a different version with Qpid.  Each version of Amqp defines it's methods in an XML file, I suggest you figure out which file your Qpid is using and check that for a definitive answer.  HTH